# How to install pgBench on Mac Os Big Sur?

Tags: postgresql

How can I install pgBench on mac os Big Sur . I have postgres 12.5 already installed and stack builder does not have the option to install pgbench . And once installed how to connect pgbench to a remote postgres server .

Comment: pgbench is part of the base Postgres installation. It's located in the same directory where `psql` is located

Answer (score 1):

If you used brew to install postgresql, you have pgbench installed. For pgbench command help run `pgbench --help.

To connect it to a remote server you'll want to pass pgbench the host, port, and username options for your target database (-h , -p , -U ) respectively.

Example:
`pgbench -h labserver -p 5432 -U postgres -i postgres`

*-i in my example is for the pgbench initialization.*